# Unable to draw lines between html elements

Tags: html, css, html5-canvas

```html
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1" %>
  <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
  <html>

  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
    <title>Available Streams</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="CSS/styleSheet.css" />

  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="set_cstext-title" class="handcursor" style="display:block; padding:0px; margin-bottom:1px; background-color:#274B7D; color:#FFFFFF; font-weight: bold; font: italic normal bold normal 30px helvetica, arial, sans-serif;">
      <img src="logo-cisco.png">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; QA Test Automation</div>

    <p align="right">
      <a class="hyperlinkblock4" href="ChangeConfig.jsp">Change Config</a> |
      <a class="hyperlinkblock2" href="LoginPage.jsp">Logout</a>
    </p>
    <div class="tabbable">

      <ul class="tabs">
        <li><a href="#CFADashBoards">CFA DashBoard Links</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#EnvironmentValidations">Data Validations</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#CubeValidations">Cube Validations</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#CompatibilityValidations">Compatibility Validations</a>
        </li>



      </ul>

      <div class="tabcontent">

        <!---------------------------------------------------- CFA DashBoards ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------->
        <div id="CFADashBoards" class="tab">
          <br>

          <!--
We will create a family tree using just CSS(3)
The markup will be simple nested lists
-->
          <div class="tree" id="tree">
            <ul>
              <li>
                <a href="#">Parent</a>
                <ul>
                  <li>
                    <a href="#">Child</a>
                    <ul>
                      <li>
                        <a href="#">Grand Child</a>
                      </li>
                    </ul>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                    <a href="#">Child</a>
                    <ul>
                      <li><a href="#">Grand Child</a>
                      </li>
                      <li>
                        <a href="#">Grand Child</a>
                        <ul>
                          <li>
                            <a href="#">Great Grand Child</a>
                          </li>
                          <li>
                            <a href="#">Great Grand Child</a>
                          </li>
                          <li>
                            <a href="#">Great Grand Child</a>
                          </li>
                        </ul>
                      </li>
                      <li><a href="#">Grand Child</a>
                      </li>
                    </ul>
                  </li>
                </ul>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>

          <br>
          <br>



        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="finbiJavaScript.js"></script>


  </body>

  </html>
```

I wanted to show a parent child tree flow for my href links in my JSP page, after googling a while I got to know it can be done via CSS.
I was referring to this site: http://thecodeplayer.com/walkthrough/css3-family-tree

However even after copying the same code it seems to not work in my page.

[image]

HTML:

```
<div class="tree" id="tree">
<ul>
    <li>
        <a href="#">Parent</a>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Child</a>
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Grand Child</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Child</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Grand Child</a></li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Grand Child</a>
                        <ul>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#">Great Grand Child</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#">Great Grand Child</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#">Great Grand Child</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Grand Child</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
* {margin: 0; padding: 0;}
.tree ul {
padding-top: 20px; position: relative;
-transition: all 0.5s;
-webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
-moz-transition: all 0.5s;
}

.tree li {
float: left; text-align: center;
list-style-type: none;
position: relative;
padding: 20px 5px 0 5px;
-transition: all 0.5s;
-webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
-moz-transition: all 0.5s;
}

/*We will use ::before and ::after to draw the connectors*/

.tree li::before, .tree li::after{
content: '';
position: absolute; top: 0; right: 50%;
border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
width: 50%; height: 20px;
}
.tree li::after{
right: auto; left: 50%;
border-left: 1px solid #ccc;
}

/*We need to remove left-right connectors from elements without 
any siblings*/
.tree li:only-child::after, .tree li:only-child::before {
display: none;
}

/*Remove space from the top of single children*/
.tree li:only-child{ padding-top: 0;}

/*Remove left connector from first child and 
right connector from last child*/
.tree li:first-child::before, .tree li:last-child::after{
border: 0 none;
}
/*Adding back the vertical connector to the last nodes*/
.tree li:last-child::before{
border-right: 1px solid #ccc;
border-radius: 0 5px 0 0;
-webkit-border-radius: 0 5px 0 0;
-moz-border-radius: 0 5px 0 0;
}
.tree li:first-child::after{
border-radius: 5px 0 0 0;
-webkit-border-radius: 5px 0 0 0;
-moz-border-radius: 5px 0 0 0;
}

/*Time to add downward connectors from parents*/
.tree ul ul::before{
content: '';
position: absolute; top: 0; left: 50%;
border-left: 1px solid #ccc;
width: 0; height: 20px;
}

.tree li a{
border: 1px solid #ccc;
padding: 5px 10px;
text-decoration: none;
color: #666;
font-family: arial, verdana, tahoma;
font-size: 11px;
display: inline-block;

border-radius: 5px;
-webkit-border-radius: 5px;
-moz-border-radius: 5px;

-transition: all 0.5s;
-webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
-moz-transition: all 0.5s;
}

/*Time for some hover effects*/
/*We will apply the hover effect the the lineage of the element also*/
.tree li a:hover, .tree li a:hover+ul li a {
background: #c8e4f8; color: #000; border: 1px solid #94a0b4;
}
/*Connector styles on hover*/
.tree li a:hover+ul li::after, 
.tree li a:hover+ul li::before, 
.tree li a:hover+ul::before, 
.tree li a:hover+ul ul::before{
border-color:  #94a0b4;
}
```

Comment: Works here: http://jsfiddle.net/xba35b9L/ Can you specify what doesn't work on your page?

Comment: I just tried with a simple HTML page it was working, however the same code when ran as a JSP page i could see only as a list (attached the screen shot)

Comment: It means that the CSS reference is wrong in the JSP page. It is not applying the CSS. Post the JSP code.

Comment: Posted the JSP code, I am referring the same sheet for some other styles in the same page, those works fine

Comment: Maybe a cache issue? Is there a demo page of it?

Comment: @ManojKumar: Thanks I guess that was the issue, i restarted the system and it was working.

Answer (score -1):

you can use `<hr>` to draw the line's in html5 pages
For Example try this code and check it

```
<h1>HTML</h1>
<p>HTML is a language for describing web pages.....</p>

<hr>

<h1>CSS</h1>
<p>CSS defines how to display HTML elements.....</p>
```

Having any queries reply

Comment: is there a way to draw connector lines using <hr> tags?